# BASH scripting: when to include the back slash symbol

Tags: bash, symbols, backslash, quoting

I am writing a BASH script and I am using the **bash** command. Which one of the following is correct (or are both incorrect)?

```
bash $pbs_dir/${module_name}.${target_ID}.${instance_ID}.pbs
```

or

```
bash \$pbs_dir/\${module_name}.\${target_ID}.\${instance_ID}.pbs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\$` will be expanded to literal `$`, so there is a big difference:

```
$ a="hello"
$ echo $a
hello
$ echo \$a
$a
```

Also note that you almost *always* want to double quote your parameter expansions to avoid [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [pathname expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs):

```
echo "$a"
```

So you properly want to use the following:

```
bash "$pbs_dir/${module_name}.${target_ID}.${instance_ID}.pbs"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of using quotations

Comment: @JamestheGreat No problem! I added a few interesting links in the answer  for future reading :-)